# Regarding the Quandl module, how would you call any stock without having to know the stock exchange

Tags: python, finance, quandl

The Quandl module makes it easy to call stock information if you know the specific label. For example, Apple would be something like GOOG/NASDAQ_APPL which means Quandl gets it from google finance, and apple is traded in NASDAQ. However, it gets annoying when I enter a bunch of stocks into the python call function and I don't know whether it is NYSE or NASDAQ. Is there a more general way to retrieve any arbitrary stock?

Comment: Doesn't look like it -- [from their API documentation](https://www.quandl.com/help/api): *Note that table codes are not guaranteed to be unique across database. SHFE/CUG2014 is not the same as MCX/CUG2014. Thus you need both the database code and the table code to fully identify a dataset.*

Comment: Also, you could always do the lookup once, manually, then add the entries to a map: `stocks = {'AAPL': 'GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL'}` or `stocks = {'AAPL': 'NASDAQ_AAPL'}`

Comment: Thanks. It seems like that's the best alternative right now!

Answer (score 1):

If your universe of stock tickers is limited to a few major stock exchanges you can follow the description of fetching stock data via Python API in Quandl given [here](http://www.quantatrisk.com/2014/11/07/covariance-matrix-for-n-asset-portfolio-fed-by-quandl-in-python/). Quandl provides .csv file of [secwiki_tickers.csv](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quandl-static-content/Ticker+CSV%27s/secwiki_tickers.csv) with a collection of 3339 stocks for which you can grab e.g. close prices (code .4 below). The Python code for doing that may look as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import Quandl

df = pd.read_csv('secwiki_tickers.csv')

dp = pd.read_csv('portfolio.lst',names=['pTicker'])
pTickers = dp.pTicker.values  # converts into a list
tmpTickers = []

for i in range(len(pTickers)):
test=df[df.Ticker==pTickers[i]]
if not(test.empty):
    tmp=test.Price.values+'.4'  # of <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    tmp2=tmp.tolist()
    tmpTickers.append(tmp2)

print(tmpTickers)
tmp = []

for i in range(len(tmpTickers)):
    tmp2 = str(tmpTickers[i]).strip('[]')
    print(tmp)
    tmp.append(str(tmp2).strip('\'\''))

QuandlTickers = tmp
print(QuandlTickers)

data = Quandl.get(QuandlTickers, authtoken='YourAuthToken', \
                 trim_start='2014-10-01', trim_end='2014-11-04', \
                 transformation='rdiff')

d=data.values.T # return-series (frequency: daily) based on close-prices
print(d)
```

where we use *portfolio.lst* as a plain text file storing a list of *N* desired stock tickers, e.g.:

```
AAPL
IBM
TXN
```

Eventually, a NumPy array with fetched daily return-series for a specified time interval is, e.g.:

```
[[-0.01558313  0.00725953 -0.0028028   0.         -0.00873319  0.02075949
   0.00218254 -0.00287072 -0.00913333 -0.01062018 -0.01225316 -0.01312282
   0.01464783  0.02139859  0.0271652   0.00507466  0.01786581  0.00372031
  -0.00104543  0.01550756  0.00562114 -0.00335383  0.00953449  0.01296296
  -0.00731261]
 [-0.01401254 -0.00138911  0.0094163   0.0019611  -0.01761532  0.0196543
  -0.01552598 -0.00262847 -0.01296187  0.00152572 -0.01115343 -0.01050894
   0.0122887  -0.0711343  -0.03471319 -0.00882191  0.00241053 -0.0006166
  -0.00129566  0.01068759 -0.00085575  0.00544476  0.00030423 -0.00024331
  -0.01040399]
 [-0.01698469         nan         nan -0.00416489 -0.01319035  0.020213
  -0.01959949 -0.07127336 -0.0189518   0.00906272  0.01063578  0.01941066
   0.00183528  0.01694527  0.05314118 -0.00320718  0.00815101  0.01212766
   0.00798823  0.01147028 -0.00350515 -0.01655287  0.0448138   0.00845751
   0.00638978]]
```

Be aware, as already mentioned in comments that you can fetch AAPL price-series skipping WIKI database of Quandl.